# If I have a Python script I started in PHP from a web server, how do I stop it?

Tags: php, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I have an Apache Web server on my RaspberryPi 4 that has a program written in Python on it that will turn on an 8x8 matrix of red led's. I have a HTML and PHP page on the web server so I can remotely execute that script. The HTML is just 2 buttons and on the press of the button it goes to this PHP program:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['on']))
  {
    lightOn();
  } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['off']))
  {
    lightOff();
  }

  function lightOn()
  {
    $command = escapeshellcmd('sudo python3 led_display.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;

  }

  function lightOff()
  {
    $command = escapeshellcmd('');
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
  }

?>
```

This PHP program just recognizes which of the 2 buttons was pressed and on the press executes a function. For the lightOn() function it is simple as I just execute the script that drives the 8x8 led matrix. However I want the user to be able to stop the script at any time by pressing the other button. On a normal command line interface I would type 'Control + c' to stop any running script. How would I achieve that in PHP through shell_exec, or any other method?

Comment: Your code is not very pretty, so: Why do you have these functions `lightOn` e `lightOff`? Are these functions used anywhere else? You have unecessary duplicated code in these two functions

Comment: being able to `sudo` triggered from some web request sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @OlafKock what is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do without using sudo?

Answer (score 0):

In your server, find out what's the process id (PID) via `ps`, `top` or even `htop` commands. Than you can kill it with the command `kill {pid_number}`.

Something like:

```sh
$ ps aux | grep led_display # the first number that appears is the PID. let's assume it's 1234
$ kill 1234
```

Comment: I tried this approach, found the pid and put 'kill {pid}' and 'sudo kill {pid}' as the command, but when I click the button the lights dont go off. The problem, I think, is that if you think about it when you run a python script in linux the user cannot give commands during runtime. I need a way to simulate Control + C while a script is running to stop it on the spot. Thank you for the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have control over the `sudoers` file and know how to make it so your web-server process can execute the command referenced in `lightOff` without a password you should be able to do

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo pkill -TERM led_display.py');
```

Of course that would terminate ANY process called `led_display.py`, not just the one you started from the web-server process.

EDIT:

What happens if you background the process?

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo python3 led_display.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Comment: I tried this and the answer above. Neither worked but I think the issue is the same as the other one. When a python script is running in linux the user cannot type. Since shell_exec is essentially like typing a command, whatever I put in the lightsOff() function wont get executed until the script is done. I need something that simulates 'Control + C' that will stop a script on the spot even if the user cannot type commands. Either way thank you for the answer.

Comment: What happens if you background the process?  See the edit above.

Comment: Sorry, I had a brainfart ... you're not meant to background the kill attempt, but the start of the led_dispaly.  Check again, please.

Comment: Does the `led_display` actually get backgrounded?  That is, if you try to print anything after `    lightOn();` - does that get printed?

Comment: No I do not believe it gets backgrounded. It just runs actively and then the next line of code is executed. How would I go about making it run in the background?

Comment: That's what (according to discussions of similar issues) `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`  should do ...

Comment: Hmmm? Im not sure what the issue is with the program but I will keep looking and trying to solve it. Thank you for the help. Any chance you could link the similar issues where > /dev/null 2>&1 & comes up?